# Jmeter - response code and failure message are empty

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter

How to get response code and failure message in an email using JMeter
I have set up some http requests and I have 2 if controllers one on success and one on failure of these requests.
inside those if controllers I am having an SMTP Sampler which sends emails 
What are the right methods to get code and response message when I am getting a failure?

I tried with these:

```
${__groovy( ctx.getPreviousSampler().getPreviousResult().getStartTime())}
${__groovy( ctx.getPreviousSampler().getPreviousResult().getResponseCode())}
${__groovy( ctx.getPreviousSampler().getPreviousResult().getResponseMessage())}

prev res code
${__groovy( ctx.getPreviousResult().getAssertionResults().getResponseCode())}

prev res failure message 
${__groovy( ctx.getPreviousResult().getAssertionResults().getFailureMessage())}

prev res failure getResponseMessage 
${__groovy( ctx.getPreviousResult().getAssertionResults().getResponseMessage())}
```

while I can get for instance the time using this:

```
${__groovy( ctx.getPreviousResult().getTime() )}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax would be:

1. For response code:

   ```
   ${__groovy(ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseCode(),)}
   ```
2. For response message:

   ```
   ${__groovy(ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseMessage(),)}
   ```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Groovy Response Code and Message]

`ctx` is a shorthand for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) class instance, see the JavaDoc for all available functions. Also check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article to learn more about Groovy scripting in JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

Add 2 [Regular expression extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of your request with the below configurations:

First regex:

- **Field to check:** Response Code
- **Reference Name:** Response_Code
- **Regular Expression:** (\d+)
- **Template:** $1$
- **Match No.** 1

Second regex:

- **Field to check:** Response Message
- **Reference Name:** Response_Message
- **Regular Expression:** (.*)
- **Template:** $1$
- **Match No.** 1

Then use the reference name of your regex in your SMTP sampler like this `${Response_Code}` which will hold the value of the response code and `${Response_Message}` which will hold the value of the response message.